# int не принимает тип int *

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели

```
int zapCopr(int c[3][3], int a[3][3], int b[3], int o)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; ++j)
            c[i][j] = a[i][j];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
        c[i][o] = b[i];
    int opr= c[0][0] * c[1][1] * c[2][2] + c[0][1] * c[1][2] * c[2][0] + c[1][0] * c[2][1] * c[0][2] - c[0][2] * c[1][1] * c[2][0] - c[2][1] * c[1][2] * c[0][0] - c[0][1] * c[1][0] * c[2][2];
    return opr;
}
```

Эта функция должна делать дела. Я вставляю функцию в код. Вставляю туда аргументы типа `arr[3][3]`, но вот и всё. Компилятор заявляет, что этот массив у меня имеет указательный тип, а нужен целый.

Comment: и я не понимаю: что куда вставляете и на какой строке ошибка?

Comment: Приведите хотя бы фрагмент кода, как вы это делаете. Сами, наверное, понимаете, что тело данной функции тут ни при чем...

Comment: @Harry Нет, не понимаю. Мне показалось, что я написал обо всём нужном. Вот, я просто присваиваю переменной значение этой функции. 
opr2 = zapCopr(c[3][3], a[3][3], b[3], 1);

Comment: @PavelKas Ну вот и все понятно - не пишите эти [3][3] и иже с ними! Вы их уже один раз написали - при объявлении. Теперь просто вызывайте `zapCopr(c,a,b,1)` То, что делали вы - это передача КОНКРЕТНОГО элемента массива, да еще и не существующего :)

Comment: @Harry Спасибо! Я везде такие ошибки допускал. И когда пытался в Паскале вызвать функцию - тоже. И вот теперь тут! Ну я и дурень. Пойду исправлять, а потом и наслаждаться лаконичным и безупречно работающим кодом. :)